# Struggling to create correct relationships in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

[image: http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/7820/croppercapture1.png]

Basically: an **award**(course) has many **units**, which can be either optional or core(mandatory), depending on the award. So for example: the unit 'Advanced Software Engineering' maybe a core unit for the award 'Software Engineering BSc' but only an optional unit for the course 'Web Technology BSc'. I've used flags for that purpose.

A **student** is enrolled on an **award** so I need to get a complete list of core and optional units (bearing in mind that a student chooses 1 out of many possible optional units).

Also, these units have **events**, e.g, a lecture, workshop or seminar, etc. and those events have **sessions** or instances of events where students enrolled on that particular unit are required to attend, and those attendances are stored in a separate table to form a register.

So I need a hierarchy of expanding the tables something like this I guess:

- Awards -> Students -> Units -> Sessions -> Attendances

Any help with this would be appreciated... It's blowing my mind and I'm really close to going insane! My tutor didn't spot I'd got it wrong when I showed my original data model to him and it's due in next week! Thank you :D

Comment: I could see your image, but I cannot follow the lines.  They overlap, go under each other, get hidden by tables, and generally make it hard to read.  Also, it is not clear to me what your question is.  Is it "does this E-R make sense?"

Comment: My question is sort of "how can I make a correct E-R model for it"

The relationships are:

students one award,
students many units,
award many units,
units many events,
events many sessions,
sessions many attendances,
students many attendances,
students one tutor group,
staff member many tutor groups,
staff member many units...

Does that help? :X

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, I do not think students need to be related to Awards or Units, but to AwardUnits. Perhaps:

```
 Awards  Units
   |       |
  AwardsUnits -- AwardsUnitsSessions
    ( AwardID            |
    ( Mandatory          ---- AwardsUnitsSessionsStudents (ie Attendances)
        |                         |
 AwardUnitsStudents--Students-----|
```

When a student is created, an Award is selected and all mandatory units from AwardUnits are added to AwardUnitsStudents and a list of optional units are presented to the user so that the student choices can be added.

EDIT
You might like to consider a persons table that contains all common person details (in quite a few cases, the address table should be separate) with additional tables to define extra information for staff, student, tutor, etc. This is a common enough style, and can make life easier, especially when one person has more than one role.

Comment: Thank you, @Remou!

So, in AwardsUnitsSessionsStudents I'd have the IDs for awards, units, sessions and that same row would be repeated for how ever many students there are required to attend an instance of a session?

and in AwardsUnitsStudents there'd be the ID of Awards and that's repeated for however many Units there are for that award, and that's repeated for however many students there are in that unit?

just checking I've understood your model =]

Comment: Yes for AwardsUnitsStudents, however, for AwardsUnitsSessionsStudents you have a few possibilities. You could enter only students that showed up, you could enter all rows for required sessions and only students that showed up for optional sessions, and so on.

Comment: @Remou Hmm... I can't pull the AwardID from AwardsUnits to AwardsUnitsStudents though can I because it's not a key in AwardsUnits?

Also, in my interface I want to allow the user to input an event, such as a lecture or a workshop, etc... and then the system automatically adds the sessions for those events on a weekly bases to AwardsUnitsStudents or whatever... The whole point of the system is to allow users to print off a list of all students who are supposed to attend and specify after that session has taken place whether they did or not.

Comment: So wouldn't it be better to have a separate Sessions table that lists all sessions in a unit so that we can list in another table the attendances that pulls the students taking that unit? I'm just haven't got that to work before =[

Comment: Another problem I have is that a student has to study for 3 years and they make their option choices at the end of level 1 and level 2 so I need to find some way of pulling a list of all possible choices and mandatory units and only specify option choices from that list when appropriate

Comment: Your original question was about relationships and these notes seem to expand on the original question. Certainly you should have a sessions table, the above is a sketch of the area around awards, not an exhaustive list of tables, furthermore, AwardsUnitsSessions implies such a table, note that other tables shown in your outline have also been omitted from the sketch, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: If the interface is not working for you, I suspect some misunderstanding may have crept in. Stackoverflow is a knowledge base, if you wish to move to a forum discussion, I can be found at lessthandot.com.